# How to suppress aspnet core logs ONLY during `dotnet test`

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

When I run `dotnet test` in my solution's root folder, I get a bunch of asp.net logs and I'd like to suppress them (only during unit tests).

Other people running the same project, don't see any logs (they're on Windows, I'm on a Mac).

```
➜ dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2.301
 Commit:    70d6be0814

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.14
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.14-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.301/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.6
  Commit:  7dac9b1b51

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.401 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.2.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.2.301 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Here's what I see:

[image: aspnet logs]